# Use of if controller for check condition in jmeter

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter

I need to add a check condition for the search result page that, if a search result is found, the script should run further otherwise it should stop on the same step.

This is my Condition in if controller:

```
${__javaScript("${depdate}"=! null)}
```

Here `depdate` is the regex parameter. If search results are found then its value will be null otherwise it will display content. It's a part of a json string.

I have put all further step in the if controller, but not success. Can anyone help me out of this? What is the reason that this is not working.

What is wrong here with what I am performing?

Comment: this is the screenshot of my script http://screencast.com/t/RpXTquRsCy7

Comment: ${__javaScript("${deptDate}" != null)} its working by this expression but its giving opposite results. means, if results found then script will stop otherwise it will run. I think issue is having in implementation. can anyone help me to solve this issue? screenshot is here: http://screencast.com/t/SucTZhiFD24

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that your `"${depdate}"` will **never** be null.

- If `${depdate}` variable is set - it will be variable value
- If `${depdate}` variable is not set - it will be **default** value (which is `${depdate}`

Demo:

[image: JavaScript variables]

So change your expression to be `${__javaScript(vars.get("depdate") != null)} and everything should start working fine.

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more information on using IF conditions in your JMeter test.

Comment: It is not really so true, is the tested variable comes from JDBC, as the `result_1` value.